# TryParse not working and if else condition not working

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a normal form where I can convert Celsius toFahrenheit  or viceversa.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double celsius;
        double fahrenheit;
        string value;
        double finalValue;

        bool successCelsius = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out celsius);
        bool successFahrenheit = double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out fahrenheit);
        if (successCelsius == false)
        {
            label6.Text = ("ERROR: Please enter a numeric temperature to convert.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            celsius = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            finalValue = (celsius * 9) / 5 + 32;
            label6.Text = finalValue.ToString();
            label6.Text = celsius + " " + "degrees Celsius converts to" + " " + finalValue + " " + "degrees Fahrenheit";
        }

        if (successFahrenheit == false)
        {
            label6.Text = ("ERROR: Please enter a numeric temperature to convert.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            fahrenheit = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            finalValue = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
            value = finalValue.ToString();
            label6.Text = fahrenheit + " " + "degrees Fahrenheit converts to" + " " + finalValue + " " + "degrees Celsius";
        }

    }
```

Textbox accepted the values and displays to label6. It checks if the entered value is a double or not and then it works.
idk why tryParse isnt working.

Can you help me out? :)

Comment: Can you expand on "_tryParse isn't working_"?

Comment: Bool successCelsius, checks if the entered value is a double and in if else condition, the else statement should work if its true, if false then the first one should work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of value you're trying and what you expect to see?

Comment: I understand what the code is _supposed_ to do, but you haven't said how it isn't working. Is it not entering the correction part of the conditional? Throwing an exception? Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger to confirm the values being parsed are what you expect them to be? If so, what are they?

Comment: You are doing some unnecessary steps - if `TryParse` succeeds, the `out` parameter (`celcius` and `fahrenheit` in your code) will be set to the parsed value. You can remove the `celcius = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);` line.

Comment: You need to describe what's not working. Your code looks fine.

Comment: You could condense your code to: `if(double.TryParse(string, out double temperature) { }`

Comment: Yeah The code only changes label6 text to ERROR: Please enter a numeric temperature to convert.
The else statement doenst work for both

Comment: What values are you inputting?

Comment: That's because you have a `return` statement in each `if`, so if the first `if` condition is true, then the method exits and the second `if` is not evaluated. Get rid of the `return` statements if you want the method code to continue executing.

Comment: I tried to enter celsius value 10

Answer (score 0):

The reason this code doesn't "work" is because of your code flow.

The way the code is structured right now, you have to enter both a celsius and a farenheit value or your code will display an "ERROR".   If textbox1 or textbox2 are empty, your code will return false from TryParse.   If you follow that logic, this code will execute (if you only enter celsius):

```
            if (successFahrenheit == false)
            {
                label6.Text = ("ERROR: Please enter a numeric temperature to convert.");
                return;
            }
```

UPDATE:
You need to handle both scenarios separately...here is one way that is simple....check for one and do it....otherwise, check the other.   THere are a lot of ways to "solve" this problem but this would be one of the easiest.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double celsius;
            double fahrenheit;
            string value;
            double finalValue;

            if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                bool successCelsius = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out celsius);

                if (successCelsius == false)
                {
                    label6.Text = ("ERROR: Please enter a numeric temperature to convert.");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    celsius = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
                    finalValue = (celsius * 9) / 5 + 32;
                    label6.Text = finalValue.ToString();
                    label6.Text = celsius + " " + "degrees Celsius converts to" + " " + finalValue + " " + "degrees Fahrenheit";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bool successFahrenheit = double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out fahrenheit);


                if (successFahrenheit == false)
                {
                    label6.Text = ("ERROR: Please enter a numeric temperature to convert.");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    fahrenheit = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
                    finalValue = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
                    value = finalValue.ToString();
                    label6.Text = fahrenheit + " " + "degrees Fahrenheit converts to" + " " + finalValue + " " + "degrees Celsius";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How can i fix this ? :)

Comment: You should like and accept his answer if this is the case.

Comment: I tried, It says 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score'